# Htaccess view image,block directory and redirect to another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have Seconddomain.com that will redirect to Firstdomain.com. I use this htaccess code and it's work fine

```
#Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.Firstdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.Firstdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Now I have to create image folder in Seconddomain to embed another web.

Example 
https://Seconddomain.com/img

I upload image example https://Seconddomain.com/img/duck.jpg, but I can't view it and will redirect to Firsdomain.com.

How can I view the image, block peole see my IMG directory and same time Seconddomain will redirect to Firstdomain.com?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's okay, I found the answers

Must create 2 htaccess, one in main folder and second htaccess into img folder

Main folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.firstdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.firstdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Second folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.firstdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.firstdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```